# python mock how to replace a function with my own but still reuse the original argument

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want to replace a method with my own method, so I found mock in python, but i'm wondering if there is some method to get a function parameter to reuse when running, because my own method mymethod should do some operation based on that????

```
class a
def thing()
    exec(argument1)



test tester():
     with patch(a.thing.exec, self.mymethod, spec=true) as mock_method
          mock_method(argument1, otherargument)
```

Comment: Is `argument1` an argument or a local variable?

Comment: it is an argument